# How are Docker cache mounts used in BuildX?

Tags: docker, docker-buildkit

When I do [`RUN --mount=type=cache`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mounttypecache) in Dockerfile how are they used?

Are they reused between different project builds each with it's own `Dockerfile`?  If so what's the key?

Comment: "*If so what's the key?*" - From the link you provided: "*`id` - Optional ID to identify separate/different caches. Defaults to value of `target`. --- `target` -  Mount path.*"

Comment: So as long as they share the same id value, the cache is reused across different projects?